# OpenCV image cropping error

Tags: python, opencv

I executed a program that reads all `.jpg` files from directory, performs face detection, crops the faces and saves them.

The problem is that when run an official python program I am able to detect all faces, but it saves only few faces from every image.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import cv2
import sys
import glob 

cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

# Create the haar cascade
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

files=glob.glob("*.jpg")   
for file in files:

    # Read the image
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect faces in the image
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    print "Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces))

    # Crop Padding
    left = 10
    right = 10
    top = 10
    bottom = 10

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print x, y, w, h

        # Dubugging boxes
        # cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)


    image  = image[y-top:y+h+bottom, x-left:x+w+right]

    print "cropped_{1}{0}".format(str(file),str(x))
    cv2.imwrite("cropped_{1}_{0}".format(str(file),str(x)), image)
```

Comment: Looks like indent problem, the cropping part should be in the ``for`` loop to save all results contained in the ``faces`` variable..

Comment: there is no error while compiling its just not detecting all faces i was thinking foe face detection there should be a loop a or some wait time  so that it can read a image and use haar cascade

Comment: Not having error does not mean the code does what you think it does. What I meant is, you have to iterate over ``faces`` to process each found bounding box for each image. Right now you're just saving only one result per image because, as a side effect, ``(x, y, w, h)`` still exist after you've printed the found bounding box. You just have to indent those three lines to include them in that loop.

Comment: # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print x, y, w, h
these three lines i am weak in programming hope u understand

Comment: My bad, I mixed up what I wrote with what I had in mind. I was talking about the last three lines of your code. Basically, add all code which is after ``for (x, y, w, h) in faces:`` into that same loop.

Comment: can you elaborate and give me correct code please

Comment: Well, just add a Tab in front of the lines ``image = ...``, ``print "cropped..."`` and ``cv2.imwrite...``..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gall said in the comments, the problem comes from your indentation. Your last three lines are not executed for each face as their indentation does not make them part of the loop over the faces. You want something like this:

```
# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
   image = image[y-top:y+h+bottom, x-left:x+w+right]
   cv2.imwrite("cropped_{1}_{0}".format(str(file),str(x)), image)
```

Note that with this code, there is a possibility of filename collision (2 faces with same in `x` in an image). You may want want to use a unique string to avoid that problem. A simple counter would do the trick.

Comment: as u said i intendend my code now it is cropping face but in the directory it is showing only one cropped face while other when i try to open it give me error no data the code is cropping face but showing only one face

Answer (score -1):

problem your code is that when the first person cuts out the image, following already tries to cut not from the original image, and already from a certain first person so it's code you look think everyone will understand

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import glob 

cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

img = cv2.imread('3.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        #flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
        flags=0
    )

print "Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces))

left = 10
right = 10
top = 10
bottom = 10
i=0
count=0

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print x, y, w, h, i
        i=i+1
        img  = img[y-top:y+h+bottom, x-left:x+w+right]
        cv2.imwrite('foo{}.png'.format(count), img)
        count += 1
        img=cv2.imread('3.jpg')
```